# Парсинг сайта jsoup

Tags: html, парсер, jsoup

Доброго времени суток. Есть сайт с проксями. Нужно спарсить прокси в таком виде:
*proxy:port Степень_анонимности*

Стянуть прокси и степень анонимности не составляет труда, ибо в тегах **< td>** нет подклассов. Но что делать с портом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
 Document doc = null;
        try {
         doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ru.proxyservers.pro/").get();
          for (Element table : doc.select("table.table.table-hover")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            
            if (tds.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println(tds.get(1).text() + ":" + tds.get(2).text()+ " " + tds.get(7).text());
            }
        }
    }
         } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 System.out.println("404"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь с примерами в [оф. документации](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/).

```
Document doc = null;
        try {
         doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ru.proxyservers.pro/").get();
         Element table = doc.select("table.table.table-hover > tbody");
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");

            if (tds.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println(tds.get(1).select("a").first().attr("title") + ":" + tds.get(2).select("span").first().text()+ " " + tds.get(7).text());
            }
    }
         } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("404"); 
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Точнее работает так же. Выводит без порта. И там у вас ошибка.  Elements tableBody = doc.select("table.table.table-hover > tbody");

Comment: Да, с tbody код поправил.
 
А какой получаете вывод?

Comment: run:
152.231.29.210: Прозрачный
И далее по тексту. Прокси есть, тип есть, порта нет.

Comment: @Obroten54 на самом деле проблема не в том как парсит... Скорее всего сайт не отдает контент основываясь на некоторых заголовках.  как мне кажется

Comment: Там порт подставляется с помощью javascript. А jsoup - только html парсер, на сколько я знаю.

Comment: @Obroten54 точно. только порт  не подставляется, а просто делается видимым)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, именно подставляется. Загрузите страницу с отключённым js и увидите, что тег span пустой изначально.

Comment: @Obroten54 я уже посмотрел. и вы посмотрите. там `.port` имеет изначально `display:none`, но он есть. А потом делается скриптом `display:inline;`.... Каких-либо догрузок портов по xhr там не происходит

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [Скрин](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1512295797.png) - если бы был просто display:none, то парсер бы работал. Я не говорю, что скрипт отправляет запрос. Порты браузер возможно получает вместе со страницей, но в соответсвующем поле самого порта нет.